# Consuming Multiple Webservices at once

Tags: c#, uiview, performance

I´ve been checking Kayak.com and many other comparison websites were they create on demand queries to multiple web services in order to display best results. I was wondering which is the best strategy to consume multiple web services at once like these website do.
thank you so much.
sebastian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Threading in one form or other.

Using FX <= 3.5, use the ThreadPool

From 4.0 on, you can use Tasks to get better control over it.

Comment: Hi Henk, thank you so much. I´m using 4.0 with C#. Do you have a link to some excerpt of Tasks functionalities?. thank you.

Comment: A little older but slightly more specific: [ContinueWhenAll and ContinueWhenAny](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/04/14/9549246.aspx)